# Как добавить ярлык(ссылку) папки с проектом в меню пуска в Lubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Как добавить ярлык папки с проектом в меню "пуска" (ну или как оно еще называется главное меню системы?) в Lubuntu, чтобы при вызове меню каталог был уже там?

Answer (score 2):

1. Идем по пути: `/usr/share/applications`. 
   Там файлы с разрешением *.desktop. Один файл - одна программа в меню.
2. Создаем или копируем такой же файл для своей программы. Настраиваем по образу и подобию.

Comment: добавлю, что, дабы не засорять систему, свой desktop-файл можно поместить в `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: А как создать такой файл,т. е. что в нем написать?

Comment: @ArturHan тут информации достаточно - https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: Там для оболочки gnome, а у меня lxde lubuntu